# Magento 2 module not working. Override fails

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, module, extensions, overrides

I am trying to write a module that filters products in a product collection. For that I have tried to override Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer. These are the files in the module:

/Viking/FilterProducts/registration.php

```
<?php 
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Viking_FilterProducts',
    __DIR__
);
?>
```

/Viking/FilterProducts/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer" type="Viking\FilterProducts\Model\Layer" />
</config>
```

/Viking/FilterProducts/etc/module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Viking_FilterProducts" setup_version="1.0.0"/>
</config>
```

/Viking/FilterProducts/Module/Layer.php

```
<?php

namespace Viking\FilterProducts\Model;


class Layer extends \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer{

    protected $_customerSession;

    protected $_resource;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\ContextInterface $context,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\StateFactory $layerStateFactory,
        AttributeCollectionFactory $attributeCollectionFactory,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product $catalogProduct,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        CategoryRepositoryInterface $categoryRepository,
        array $data = []
        ) {
            $this->_resource = $resource;
            $this->_customerSession = $customerSession; 
            parent::__construct(
                $context,
                $layerStateFactory,
                $attrubuteCollectionFactory,
                $catalogProduct,
                $registry,
                $categoryRopository,
                $data
            );
    }

    //Old funciton with print statement
    public function getProductCollection(){

        if (isset($this->_productCollections[$this->getCurrentCategory()->getId()])) {
            $collection = $this->_productCollections[$this->getCurrentCategory()->getId()];
        } else {
            $collection = $this->collectionProvider->getCollection($this->getCurrentCategory());
            //Will filter products here
            $this->prepareProductCollection($collection);
            $this->_productCollections[$this->getCurrentCategory()->getId()] = $collection;
        }

        echo 'New Layer <br />';

        return $collection;
    }




}
?>
```

It is still the old Layer that is called. I have overridden other classes in the same way but this time it doesn't work and I don't know why.Been stuck at this point really long now. No error messages.

removing constructor (which will be used) does not make any difference.

**Edit**

I changed the module.xml file as @dersam suggested but it did not help. I also added an composer.json file in Viking/FilterProducts that look like this:

```
{
    "name": "Viking/FilterProducts",
    "type": "magento2-module",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "require": {
        "php": "~5.5.0|~5.6.0|~7.0.0",
        "magento/module-catalog": "~100.0"
    }
}
```

This did not make any difference either but I am not sure if it is correct. (I ran disable/enable command and then setup and compile commands). The module shows up as enabled when running module:status.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I know the problem. You are overriding the incorrect class. Layer model used in layered navigation is created in a constructor of `Magento\LayeredNavigation\Block\Navigation` class by this piece of code

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Resolver $layerResolver,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\FilterList $filterList,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\AvailabilityFlagInterface $visibilityFlag,
    array $data = []
) {
    $this->_catalogLayer = $layerResolver->get();
    $this->filterList = $filterList;
    $this->visibilityFlag = $visibilityFlag;
    parent::__construct($context, $data);
}
```

`$layoutResolver->get()` method looks like this:

```
public function get()
{
    if (!isset($this->layer)) {
        $this->layer = $this->objectManager->create($this->layersPool[self::CATALOG_LAYER_CATEGORY]);
    }
    return $this->layer;
}
```

So it creates a class based on a list of layerPool property which is set in layoutResover class constructor. By default this array contain 2 values:

```
[
     'category' => 'Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Category',
     'search' => 'Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Search'
]
```

So either create a preference for the class you want to change it, probably `Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Category` or change the class name passed to layoutResolver class. The original setup can be found in `Magento_Catalog/etc/di.xml`:

```
<type name="Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Resolver">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="layersPool" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="category" xsi:type="string">Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Category</item>
            <item name="search" xsi:type="string">Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Search</item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
```

Comment: Yes! That was the problem. Thank you very much!

Comment: how to change the class name passed to layoutResolver class? I add `<item name="outlet" xsi:type="string">Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Outlet</item>` but still get `Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Category`

Comment: @krybbio it won't work that way. This settings sets 2 keys in the layersPool, category and search. Magento internally accesses them by that key. Your config adds new item to the pool but no code uses it. If you want to use different object you need to overwrite the key depending where you want to use your class.

Comment: @Zefiryn, you're right. it must be declared in controller: 
`public function execute()
    {
  $this->layerResolver->create('outlet');
  
        $this->_view->loadLayout();
        $this->_view->renderLayout();
    }`

Answer (score 1):

Your module doesn't depend on Magento_Catalog. It's possible that the base catalog preference is being merged into the xml after yours, which would cause yours to be ignored.

Try adding `Magento_Catalog` as a dependency in your module.xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Viking_FilterProducts" setup_version="1.0.0">
      <sequence>
        <module name="Magento_Catalog" />
      </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

See http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/build/module-load-order.html.

Comment: Also check if your module is enabled with `php bin/magento module:status`

Comment: The module is enabled when running model status @Zefiryn

Comment: Thanks for the response! I added the xml code and disable/enabled the module, then ran setup and compile commands but it still doesn't work. In the link they mention that one might have to use a composer.json. I tried adding one but I don't know if it is right

Comment: Try move preference to  `Viking/FilterProducts/etc/frontend/di.xml`

Comment: @Zefiryn I tried moving di.xml to Viking/FilterProducts/etc/frontend but no difference

Comment: @RickardJohansson Yes, I think I found out why. Check my answer.